# progress bar not invoked by macro

Tags: excel, vba, progress-bar

I have tested and tried to implement a progress bar in my macro. But somehow, the progress bar is not shown and I am now trying to find out why.

I have implemented the progress bar and code in the external file where macro is that is loaded when templates are refreshed. Furthermore, there is an application.screenupdate = false line in the macro.

Therefore I am wondering if that last line influences the progress bar.

I tried it in the template itself. the progress bar is shown at 0% but nothing else happens. When I cancel the progress bar (click on 'x' in the right upper corner of the progress bar), the macro continues.

this is the macro that is executed in the external script file:

```
Sub vernieuwalles(mytemplate As String)
Dim workbook_Name As Variant
Dim workbookdirectory As String
Dim activewb As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

  Windows(mytemplate).Activate

  On Error GoTo Err_

UserForm1.Show

  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'  Call SheetOpschonen


counter = 0
Call progress

  Call datawissen

counter = counter + 1
Call progress

  For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Output Totaal" Then Call ASW
    Next i

counter = counter + 1
Call progress


  Call dataplaatsen

counter = counter + 1
Call progress

  Call kolomtitels

counter = counter + 1
Call progress

  Call toevoegen

counter = counter + 1
Call progress

  Call maaktabel

counter = counter + 1
Call progress

  Call refreshpivots

counter = counter + 1
Call progress

If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite

ActiveWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

activewb = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)

workbookdirectory = "M:\Commercie\Marktdata\IRi\Segment Ontwikkeling\"

workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel binary sheet (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", InitialFileName:=workbookdirectory & activewb)

If workbook_Name <> False Then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=workbook_Name, FileFormat:=50

ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly

ActiveWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit_:
  Application.StatusBar = ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Exit Sub

Err_:
  Call MsgBox(Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
  Resume Exit_

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

For controlling the progress bar, I have this code:

```
Sub code()

Dim pctCompl As Single

    pctCompl = counter / 7
    progress pctCompl

If pctCompl.Value = 1 Then Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub progress(pctCompl As Single)

    UserForm1.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "Completed"
    UserForm1.Bar.Width = pctCompl

    DoEvents
    'UserForm1.Hide
    End Sub
```

the template self has this code to start the script file:

```
Option Explicit
Sub vernieuwalles()
Dim myTemplate As String: myTemplate = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim myTool As String: myTool = "refresh_segment_template.xlsm"


  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Workbooks.Open GetPath & myTool
  Application.Run myTool & "!vernieuwalles", myTemplate

  Call Windows(myTool).Close(False)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetPath() As String
Dim myPosition As Integer
Dim myPath As String: myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  myPosition = InStr(StrReverse(myPath), "\") - 1
  myPosition = Len(myPath) - myPosition

  GetPath = Mid(myPath, 1, myPosition - 1) & "\XLAM\"

End Function
```

I am now wondering if I should start the progress bar from the external script file or from the template. Because when I do start it from the template, nothing happens but a progress bar is shown at 0%.

The userform is (also) in the external template file included.
The script runs fine, except for the progress bar that is not shown. And I cannot find the reason for that.

The method to update the progressbar is inspired by what is written in the tutorial on the wellsr website.

Comment: UserForm1.Repaint in sub progress?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821654/progressbar-inside-userform/51826258#51826258) if it could be of any help to you.

Comment: along with @dee 's comment in right direction, other issues also observed   it  seems  you are calling `Sub Progress` without any parameters directly from `Sub vernieuwalles`. Whereas actual progress is calculated in `Sub code()` and may be called through `Sub Code` only.